# Order a hash array by an array key

Tags: ruby, arrays

I am trying to filter and reorder an array of hashes. The filter and the order is defined by another array of strings, which represent the value of the `"slug"` key of the hash. The resulting array should contain only the hashes whose value to the `"slug"` key is contained in the slugs array and ordered with the same order. If I have the first array as:

```
data = [
  {
    "slug" => "lemon",
    "label" => "Lemon Label"
  },
  {
    "slug" => "table",
    "label" => "Table Label"
  },
  {
    "slug" => "peach",
    "label" => "Peach Label"
  },
  {
    "slug" => "strawberry",
    "label" => "Strawberry Label"
  },
  {
    "slug" => "bread",
    "label" => "Bread Label"
  },
  {
    "slug" => "orange",
    "label" => "Orange Label"
  }
]
```

and the second array as:

```
ordered_keys = ["orange", "lemon", "strawberry"]
```

then, the result should be an array like this:

```
result = [
  {
    "slug" => "orange",
    "label" => "Orange Label"
  },
  {
    "slug" => "lemon",
    "label" => "Lemon Label"
  },
  {
    "slug" => "strawberry",
    "label" => "Strawberry Label"
  }
]
```

I managed to get just the filtering function with this:

```
result = data.select{|x| ordered_keys.include? x.slug}
```

but I cannot find a smart way to get the ordered one. Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `map` to translate your array of ordered keys into the corresponding hash. The order of the input array to `map` defines the order of the output array.

```
ordered_keys.map{|k| data.find{|h| h["slug"] == k}}
```

Comment: Yes! That's exactly what I was looking for. A smart and concise way to get the result. Awesome!